# Can I migrate some users to a new email server while keeping the majority using the old one?

Tags: email-server

I am running a small email server for a small of group of people (~30, one domain) and after having several issues with it, I would like to test the Zoho servers.

Will it be possible to only migrate a couple of them to new Zoho accounts (for testing purposes) while having the rest using the old server without any issues on their end?

The basic idea is that I don't want to migrate all of them at once and find out later that something is not right. I'm thinking of adding new MX records for Zoho servers with different priorities and keeping the old ones intact, but I don't know if this is the right thing to do.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can't use MX records for that as they govern (external) routing of email at the level of your whole domain and not at the level of individual mailboxes. - Some mail servers do provide functionality to route mailboxes to different back-ends but don't expect that to be trivial to set up and configure.

Comment: That's what I though but was not sure. Thanks for the confirmation

Comment: You might be able to if both systems support SMTP namespace sharing. You'll need to look at the documentation for both systems to see if they do.

Answer (score 0):

Like Bob said certain mail servers has a feature like "if user is not found on this server, route to another host". Might not be that hard to set up if it's not Exchange, some servers has it as a GUI option. But you'd need the option on both servers so internal email would route correctly.